# Ruby style link :all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im very new to ruby, learning from some tutorials in a book i bought. I'm aware the books going to date quick and i think possibly already has.
I'm trying to get the follow code to load my stylesheets and my js to the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

However this is not working, when i load my rails server and locally view my app from the tut, the css and js are both not loading. There is no reference to them in the head. Is this a date way to do it or perhaps something else is wrong? Any help would be appreciated, like i said im totally new and not a dev by trade so go easy on me.
Regards
V

Using rails 1.9.3-p0

Comment: Could you add the version of Rails you are using? Depending on that, the answer will be different ...

Comment: `csrf_meta_tags` == Rails 3.1

Comment: Added version to the question. Sry about that

Answer (score 4):

First of all I advise you to look for information on asset pipeline for rails 3 ( you can start with [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline))

To load your js files change

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

to

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and your `application.js` should be sth like

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

the last line loads your js files from assets folder

Comment: Thank you, I will try when I get bk from work. What about the style sheet link? I had it set to :all but it was not pulling in any stylesheets

Comment: It is similar, you there use only `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`, no other file. Have a look at the RailsCast, it explains that all  well.

Comment: Thank you both mliebelt and bohdan. Tonight I'll try this.. My book obviously is written for older ruby versions. I'll take a look at some rails casts. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeh I'm regretting buying it now, I'll stick to these links. I'm looking forward to checking them out.